# Polyglot Quiz (Robbers' thread)

Tags: cops-and-robbers, polyglot

*This is the robbers' thread.  For the main rules to this challenge see the [cops' thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/251450/polyglot-quiz-cops-thread)*

In this challenge, robbers will choose a cop's *vulnerable* or *safe* post and try to figure out a pair of languages such that they print the correct results for the 4 programs.

When you find a solution post an answer of it here and leave a comment on the original post linking to your answer.

### Scoring

Robbers will be given 1 point for every *vulnerable* or *safe* they solve.  The goal of the robbers' thread is to gain as many points as possible.

### Languages and Output

In the interest of fairness, we are going to require that languages are free and reasonably cross platform. Both languages you choose must be freely available on Linux and FreeBSD (the two largest foss operating systems). This includes languages which are free and open source.

Your selected languages must predate this challenge.

Since this challenge requires that **A** and **B** produce different outputs for the same program, there is no requirement for what "counts" as a different language, the fact that they produce different outputs is enough.

Programs do not have to compile, run without error or "work" in the cases where they do not need to output **S**.  As long as **S** is not the output it is valid.

Programs here should be complete programs, not functions, expressions or snippets.

Answer (score 6):

## A = [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), B = [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), [AZTECCO](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251461/92689)

1. Try it online in [Haskell](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM8@2oCgzr0TJOb9A6f9/AA) and [Ruby](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/PzcxM8@2oCgzr0TJOb9A6f9/AA).
2. Try it online in [Haskell](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM8@2oCgzr4RLQck5v0Dp/38A) and [Ruby](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/PzcxM8@2oCgzr4RLQck5v0Dp/38A).
3. Try it online in [Haskell](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM8@Wq6AoM69EyTm/QOn/fwA) and [Ruby](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/PzcxM8@Wq6AoM69EyTm/QOn/fwA).
4. Try it online in [Haskell](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM8@2oCgzr4RLyTm/QOn/fwA) and [Ruby](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/PzcxM8@2oCgzr4RLyTm/QOn/fwA).

This would also work with A = [Curry (PAKCS)](https://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/%7Epakcs/).

Answer (score 5):

## A = [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), B = [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), [Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251468/96039)

1. Both Hexagony and Labyrinth

```
"123_1234!@
```

Try it online in [Hexagony](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/1/J0Mg4HohNFB3@/wcA) and [Labyrinth](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P9fydDIOB6ITRQd/v8HAA)

2. Only Hexagony

```
123+1
234!@
```

Try it online in [Hexagony](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/9/QyFjbkMvI2ETR4f9/AA) and [Labyrinth](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P/f0MhY25DLyNhE0eH/fwA)

3. Only Labyrinth

```
1234@
;!;!;
```

Try it online in [Hexagony](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/9/QyNjEgctaEQj//wcA) and [Labyrinth](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P/f0MjYxIHLWhEI//8HAA)

4. Neither Hexagony nor Labyrinth

```
;!;!;
1234@
```

Try it online in [Hexagony](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/99aEQi5DI2MTRz@/wcA) and [Labyrinth](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P/fWhEIuQyNjE0c/v8HAA)

Answer (score 3):

## A = [HQ9+](https://esolangs.org/wiki/HQ9%2B), B = [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), [thejonymaster](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251453/96039)

Not sure if this was the intended solution but it works!

Also, it seems that some implementations of HQ9+ are case insensitive which invalidates this crack, but I am specifically using the HQ9+ implementation on DSO, which is case sensitive.

1. Both HQ9+ and Python 3 work

```
#console.log("Hello, world!")/*
print("hello, world!".capitalize())
#*/
```

Try It Online in [Python 3](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Xzk5P684PydVLyc/XUPJIzUnJ19HoTy/KCdFUUlTX4uroCgzr0RDKQNFQi85sSCzJDEnsypVQ1OTS1lL//9/AA) and [HQ9+](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJocTkrIiwiIiwiI2NvbnNvbGUubG9nKFwiSGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkIVwiKS8qXG5wcmludChcImhlbGxvLCB3b3JsZCFcIi5jYXBpdGFsaXplKCkpXG4jKi8iLCIiLCIiLCIiXQ==)

2. Only HQ9+ works

```
console.log("Hello, world!")/*
print("hello, world!")
*/
```

Try It Online in [Python 3](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Pzk/rzg/J1UvJz9dQ8kjNScnX0ehPL8oJ0VRSVNfi6ugKDOvREMpA1WCS0v//38A) and [HQ9+](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJocTkrIiwiIiwiY29uc29sZS5sb2coXCJIZWxsbywgd29ybGQhXCIpLypcbnByaW50KFwiaGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkIVwiKVxuKi8iLCIiLCIiLCIiXQ==)

3. Only Python 3 works

```
#console.log("Hello, world!")/*
print("Hello, world!")
#*/
```

Try It Online in [Python 3](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Xzk5P684PydVLyc/XUPJIzUnJ19HoTy/KCdFUUlTX4uroCgzrwRDgktZS///fwA) and [HQ9+](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJocTkrIiwiIiwiI2NvbnNvbGUubG9nKFwiSGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkIVwiKS8qXG5wcmludChcIkhlbGxvLCB3b3JsZCFcIilcbiMqLyIsIiIsIiIsIiJd)

4. HQ9+ and Python 3 both don't work

```
console.log(String.fromCharCode(49-1)+"ello, world!")/*
print(String.fromCharCode(49-1)+"ello, world!")
*/
```

Try It Online in [Python 3](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Pzk/rzg/J1UvJz9dI7ikKDMvXS@tKD/XOSOxyDk/JVXDxFLXUFNbKTUnJ19HoTy/KCdFUUlTX4urAKi0hHgdXFr6//8DAA) and [HQ9+](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJocTkrIiwiIiwiY29uc29sZS5sb2coU3RyaW5nLmZyb21DaGFyQ29kZSg0OS0xKStcImVsbG8sIHdvcmxkIVwiKS8qXG5wcmludChTdHJpbmcuZnJvbUNoYXJDb2RlKDQ5LTEpK1wiZWxsbywgd29ybGQhXCIpXG4qLyIsIiIsIiIsIiJd)

Comment: Smart. I was looking for a cursed combination of JS and Python. (btw this works with Ruby)

Comment: @emanresuA that was the joke :P edit: ooh ruby i gotta be more careful

Comment: Correct interpreter even! this was mainly a joke, thank you for playing

Comment: it works with Crystal as well.

Answer (score 2):

## A = [Python](https://www.python.org/), B = [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), [alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9288/alephalpha)

1. Try it online in [Python](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhZrCooy80o0lJzzC5Q0IUJQGZgKAA) and [PARI/GP](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMGCpaUlaboWawqKMvNKNJSc8wuUNCFCUBmYCgA).
2. Try it online in [Python](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhZrCooy80o01J3zC9Q1IUJQGZgKAA) and [PARI/GP](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMGCpaUlaboWawqKMvNKNNSd8wvUNSFCUBmYCgA).
3. Try it online in [Python](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhZrCooy80o01J3zCzTVIUJQGZgKAA) and [PARI/GP](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMGCpaUlaboWawqKMvNKNNSd8ws01SFCUBmYCgA).
4. Try it online in [Python](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhZrCooy80o0lJzzCzSVIEJQGZgKAA) and [PARI/GP](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMGCpaUlaboWawqKMvNKNJSc8ws0lSBCUBmYCgA).

Instead of Python, it could be Ruby, Perl, Raku, or a zillion other languages.

Answer (score 2):

## A = Python 2.7, B = [SunSip](https://github.com/TvoozMagnificent/SunSip), [Number Basher](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251467/91213)

Only STDOUT is considered output, all programs liberally print garbage to standard error.

1. Both SunSip and Python2.7

```
print('0')
out
```

Try it online in [Python 2](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728oLIkIz_PaMGCpaUlaboW6wqKMvNKNNQN1DW58ktLIIJQOZgaAA) and [SunSip](https://tio.run/##7V1td9s2sv6uX4Eq9y4lW1IlJ@1NtKv0pK3T9Tmp7eO46e7Kujq0CElsKFLLlzheXf/23AHAN5AABVqSLTd0T2NZHAwGM88MwMEQXN76c8d@/nLpfvnyDL1/9/vp@9Mfz1vIcVH9fWCj9@ayXoML5mJpYfROt2eBPsPo97njYXSqLzB6P3cCy0Cnjo9@xOjcdWwnsCfYqNWgjeP6yNVtw1lEfy10fx599m696KMTf3JxrWbgKbrGU8fFYzewG81@rYbgx5wiG7rR2raGTJs07@ju7FMfLV3T9hvala0d9LrdbjOi1trtObaWYmpNo2Tvb21f/wzfMk2AgKbdWd4ClTNz9UXHs25sz75eoqGz9E3H9ka02Rn7o0//ID@sK/jQByVAB8ifmx6i3y2w5xGtgSIQ/mz6naSREX7oo5/xdTBDC8fAqcs3yWXT06/BBDe6a5v2zEsR2TkiG99Ypo09pBsGNsjop2CXdL84bvPGshB2Xcf10FQ3LeSZFrZ96zZF3PaojoCYKQvNzdncgv/JIDHynMCdYDQB0UVDdOOufgPMuOZkziwAo2ghD2PKg34Ngw@scPhgnuZfqdEIu0azltj0E2/PuKfYrlfd58@Hr3qLD9i9Jjj9lUgGxiDg8YIlgRloxTMBpuio0@10aYPuAvADvbKeDGKOMTEHGkCfBtcno2DKHkcWoXQ3ebpPTIqI11vd8jC9YDug96QLzDelJM8QNkwiLNER@CO4I6du30G@/hGThuFV@rVhungCNiRmX9C2U9P1fASMgwVYF@g9H@sGcqZw1XWC2RzpyMeffSC0mHQh/kG0SKRhb9TxlpbpU2xxJgkRIjVMxIq4aOcPx7Qb4XchEzbWMMqEIPt7BDLsIggF4QATet@97aMoaAB84gv48wQvfXRCLx0TaCeiCHFyCQpi2EN1wqkODoQNj2j3GlNd6ZaFjQ4Pk4gd1TFp1lno7sdgGcmEvYm@BI/wqGLN/@BEdBLfmMbGsSs1CFWTl5RaZBC1ZxQcgRP4y4CQhMEs@mHez1oym9HoyDcmSiWExGi0Ad85@bmZAxzoxQ4owfW9G9OfNzSkNfO0KXkOQaChY0MsN0ZoCKPVAwtivI3CjyNN2JoKM6C/hr3@KEcDUGMkZLzrBRD0CzoQNps4JB4FuJa/sFhATGuhg3EoWaROlNFmaoIai2WDqyE7OgLyGXxRMpDsYJ49pz@jqJVSoxIawFZKPADEUDNtrYU0YEd@kZFrIxVRpyDrixfTabc7WoX87h5AWu@juSSCXuuTj@T3zPEd8pvMHuQ3BMTA9TD5CMxhNIb6cF69evlyx8PxsKowRLNbE6amLskG6J0m8F0RIN3tG3pJYMF2Y9wkQ@vJ6dYjHa3Gw@6oYIAbDHI9UpTli@2BVnVUZzPymMTc5m5EV/dXBee8v7Wyjrxv1pLI9/jWYlE0DqL3jpzCkTR3HA9IuPJwUaiK1sV0DY@0SK4iBMZNYGHkmssGBaMGGC5jb8WguDEKRfJyCzpY6cqWdLK40u1OpymkauiqsHlq2UknMR1uTUerlFR0VVUHQeot1GsS2BOhSnFdLXVAZ0POtAceMyrDc1XE68Ethm0jWoAD0B7SXs@fv3w5maTt5Yb6AElig90PBL5TxHbnaia6RPTGdaqhRBIYzKPqN9ED2li/W3IjtE0/Qg/kSOUm4GhxvbuAnJuZJro10XazNM1AMoHZvq1RiwUtDXvGbutLJa69i/3AtcNmfGZnhv3xJ90KcIP@O9a9MYng9izKY0c/9DIsOTJkPJFp@3iG3fFS930MPQ6Qq/1v@4dht/1qdPhf/KAALC7uLHR/Mm9k2rVYL4JJIxwJyYkxEr7/Z2hqObrfz3xJ5iFQECY7BTZEmDaazHVXn0BfLeQ5i@hC/K3HEmX1bu/o@Yvvvv@fl6/qrQzPVOJrjmEZlmZJ3EWRbYYrzTqHWiFRZzLHk49EVTR3TTWO6EXs0a9ChXV4NVAlCI1wcNVhvwuMwbWWmwKahJgAGHa0fowQrdvRiqnbHHlbRB8amsoiMfX7iQlB2pyaE7Kho5MtDpIjDrHklQGB1LbU21ibhePiYoRQi1iY6A3VcQFiCD5Uue4EIN7EtJ0xaErsqXitw@YYyHFCs/lk82TikFmE0UWJSSxITKZ8nLZtogPU66KDA/oV46MKBoqf7UFBNVakmXdUmJeIGDzMjgtg9lRHuEPIF0bGA/bhOPfNWkdQDJmFrnAsztGzzTC2ixD9ASFWK6ZtlyHulOKsQB0NkAkdD3c9dbsceack97X03KyTCT7sS0n4YTCUxhmtLllxZMJ/sfvoENLoTr5ucRyljS4dCJmGOdF9jHSuCdLZdji26b4qE1/eOyGjg/FvHGQ4Adm3/3fg@Di1tb9VZ6WEvJ/WOwf1H4o8kWsjd0JuISvbumOemeQw6rIMBs@t3@6NZKCiFFncxAaRQ0fLQSez0uRgkaLuSM1Z1wALN6ZlwS2ADVZkS9hUU7KPbBqYQKNe342J4754K19pnSutyMy5dptYOm0auHur1aRL1uEIYkdIbpkeKfKQ0q7uEloPF5L@7XWOrZz4NqG9dDP7vxyhnRCyCg7R3eApoIu/F/Rvl3jcEGkTuJserS2wJ@GdYgtdO47VjDvSyJ/a@lawhks1MrO7w8I2NPSmWtG/FdoBGFOtGDQVmhFDpNrprqvfqvSG061IEl@kds0GvWu84lkOS6R4DsJRblVueEv3/MT2Wrd7dPTypaaEKCD@/vtuV1NClUZIs8QAH1LFQUGUSSs0eZlhSqLxyr2FBqucV1JU9JE2mZBsi9bKEzAAFJKE1gaaFy/owAQ0zLJAcnREFSVig/1iAmpOoGDZuAzFnQgByeiHoKwRDwVS0ddoCmuArmyNLkaimsGUkVRqB6OfbA0hq@1RqCKMfnLVhJmqwjI1hfLquXTllGAhbeExqYMBbdFJX1T/xbWK6qxsA38WlFml1RwWWl3Zp05cDeYt8QRuLkldlTSZqJGJkUx4oR6Y8mjlkrRJQPVCyFMFW82/5shLaYetHZbYbkj0REpMtCap9pqKVzWJPqcdF@tGJuaEynwL3OFm@60T2EahTqexUt87rnvbQidoAqsWUn40hQVqWPRn4b5UUVNtJRnLXUfe5sr@ia5NwlXIvIVsfYHZqomwg4H4GFY6jl3I5C1YMDFUCz4L7Jy2n7L5aCUe01GuxC4qOkw1YcGhlioeTFiCUGNamEpudFxBeWYYfWIIJEWjrVx5aCtmV6uVbAD9p6uhazUIT9E1hg9aCxkXIkYViFQLtXUlkfcvhyR1kLnUPHz3xiKLSN03P2ELkOksTHZnRJU4tfRZppKyFk/YEQJjS/UztahDM95vJ0HAJDYJr46ypIQ2rtWDpWgr2dvnrpDdgZECuz@4rv8gtKasHY@MWsJGPExi0QQL/cTH7XNG0b@yV5F3UndI6Sy9KOhHdcNhyrZfW5ueK5863fR@RWVLo9RWhmQLg9u62OaWxXa3KjZVp/rWRIktCbWtCNUtCOnWg@KWg0J@ebtbDBttLWxq0FJbCSW3EJS3DkpsGShtFdzDhFtJnG91S0B1K2CfRrJFSG6U6i@d4ldO7auk9JVS@UopfLXUvVrKXjFVr5iiV03Nl0zJ86n4e6fgS6XeN065l0m1b@wca1LrZVLq8gSrSgq9IHWeT5nnUuVbTJFvmhrf1CQqqfCSKXC5ZYQpb5VUt0KKWym1vTalrZDKJredcMfx4c27347RilLfodOzS3Rx/NPZL@jNJXp3cgpXJoHrwlw/JiVyh727MAyH/Lq1TNK7hSa6i6eBNegSjbomucX1Bqu7ULGkGI4R8AnsRGKS0TDtpC0tL4u7CL8cUtpRrLISmfUyGfWymfSSGfSSmfMyGfPQupFdL/95fpwYl@QKubHS5xOpYFwGndWpEdXHSelwLZ/GWEgwiHLOEaR9t5g6SkCr0sfZ6LBBXasfMsiENZOs9WDQY5CBaMmuH8InCU8Ki/xNUKLQ29wsqtkyZlEqPCIcaodaK0xAhNo1U2kMJu6hNpLxY3nziNtKjdud0P7vLy@UfDvBRZehgjyha2KDCkUyh59geoc5IEKf79Ar4PUpTq2o1YDEoxBLZJlaBCXyXSNkR2tfSYq/H3VAGrFPw5jRKGqaYh2T9fn5L3IfJlc/Us/Jr@fvmG/8dHb6YV3My3bFAheZG2Mp87DmboGFXFiDHB/OmeJMx7ff9iRsQvfI8YlnOq2fm7iEjBiMc3w4NJL5qmhMhDjHIeMfHn0sv0HntfQOl7JAPnmUTGxoBWnC5rWkXgL@ps/8etzYqOvTIy063jyYTi3coKS5O2f6bQmgsNjDif/NoFsKIwIWryUcKKkiyJplWAjxnrAqidYMRrLGUOZTDq0yJjzCBMLw1Pz8xE2opZAtcFmYTEpgW8RgpZWCVopFPvv3GnUTxoeC9ODf0gTt/Bza1Uo4yuOIIkZ7kSyKqwYlCAiDw3BUAgNCDtx9RtYJCNg3E0Sss4xPl2ucc@RSwSnjwVIFSgKAcPCaVo4JF2OTdWo5JsIomzArs0DJmuMAZrcZbvRabLHca45KMMuZJ8usjGRZa6lKJglh0oEmS6nSPKXj5XiWW@lJh60ipyR@lAMd9jfkIJHifqgViqPEKlzW/3Z6/I9zdHxxUbSip7c3Fva8ht5C1/wdTJKsYLcqejOvEh1mFtndEbCjxBmuQqaZga1jy8hVGGfXI@s4h/QqrPm4uI4xpVZhGzpsPHdew3K8iDGjF3GOjjuit8bMnRZw30zwojdbFM7XzWa@QpPhYWiOABL0Xx4VRaWjtClrpBc0TY4DS60OmFygRiaY2JzciQbrVEOoZYoJ0yXA9/Ug7FEiXqxCPV/LGiXqrouHRlVFn5J0sQ7rJqG3JXogOgQFZkUnDPC/A926t7MOBrvx1jV8N3HXNaw38Nc1nB/JYSPxBoPrHXtAdMMraa5LRE0SWxTqVKrck8plx59lyiYmF5PKrUaG0AabB7TytUVqgfQFptttSbI88YVUdVEtV0lo/8T4onfAt8/PjnepjdakwUnSNdCnBBGTn8fCAXUiqZj4QyR9n@xDhJ/zpCwK0Ck@LIZNRktiUbaerp86aTCgm0sGmjiWw04XjKgE8kR1cb@/uTg9Of0FpAr7u0vXJzIzBfHJhikrADLJkwGJeKkr7FKfI16xGue0FeDbbi1XncqO52v3YKbgiNnEwdfQJc@Tx7Yi5WiMZphuPopSgbEqYoNJW2RKg@8L19yTGtQH@kDtebXcMQrcUNguuxphfHiZIr1pa8KHtdOKkZ9JSIrJ6VME3D6W/ISEZFeLNRuRyGYvA78hz75nWking@Y9zp@LV9E/H79FH95cINIHOjkVLKXvtGapYXX3RAlyBQDXMalwZqWbobWFT41w6Z@w0e4NHnW1Y5Ovon7uNjF8LOzOTF9WHUJ3J6cGPqC/s5nmK/Lt3Q34cf1YdVx/Qp/d1dCF/kmP83yCDtoilWgDTfvqHFU@8D@Lw27VtE/TccUqEDqw@DRO7jZDQ9ph8sWhhoQnUSSH9yW0xXCidxvjqJYvjazwgSB6FGYJFtG3ETRTV5XRGt68pCDPPKqoYVLPV3x6nCjScQMo6CrGLteAPuWuJFn47HRGXXzQkJ@SlzT7JnWXnLZd6uGn8PvmesG@yd1yc64SE5aIVdw@Q1HJULFXkCORH3Ba41IGhwNUJs7L8qNPYFLb9bAfd0orP7p0ZN@RWR9yQtutAoSOe81Xjj2s47Y3RvBh70m67k4GvkfO294Cdrdj2kdz3x2oQOjA9OUDj@XAG8O4/TT9dxfj3iP33QJ020/be7evAaHz0ndT9NG1i/WPCls/4uO2p4EdbkwdpF8GIbg/FGgr3WKYtBeegifb0IoFjiRhG@qGYZI/5HFHt6zGMNwWDztukQK5aEdtMGC1dWSPM/X6t0TmUcF7BLxgUWhuKdPi479TLzfIPd7VX3vSdx7gETMJwPO3X8VQj9gVQz3Sj9ISM2ZZYo0tC6/Q6T3CQmjKTmXMrRpTXs@ziTnzgcALrn1SaP54sSD9RpJhd1TS1nI7e/SI/3vaOm8Uwq7Y1swT1M1MOZb0W6mGyXPDX5E/tZ9GcPzqsV0ujFXovie6H2q2WASWb4JgE/3RF4@9ar1RoJ@Dp7R47FWLx@0a86HCgWF@Mr3iQGDfNoZSSyDHLTlTjQaDbvE0URQ5Qrv@fPIB/fhP9K/ji7P7mFM9NcVet1ctnqvF817Fk2@rxXO1eK7Q/eCLZ3L0saM6V@5ynqzmyGqOrKJIYRT572qOrObICt0PPUcunRvuyJtH24ho9/bYmUC4bXsTYbm1qaLd63fJGbFfiUeR45GDxWCw8YQBizblgdOV2fnZ7/deoqWwMuitpSIvczHtABcS0reFlMWeRBfkzGjZnBjHD/b2kX9h1/k5TEVJ3m2zm1WuajnDjub7rzRGbWvKryLUfSb9R4lRIgfq7SYUCQf9NQaj/OKMnJojWZv5Ln10JndeUdoLU2ck0WOBIkdstnuqqzJzmwHP3G7AM9fEO34gh1uN3YTddgdzuC58hxanv8gZavRIJYleWvI@VMK4CLG@K3yQKgvZ8DCoCrUVaoWojQ4L2zvg0kPIKthWsBXClh1RVx606jC9VIPp0llKQJrUrh8OUMz4AH1X224ecwe3NGXzl3StKTxcpmQ6c@3abt2P@OA74evUU0vWohftZtR8fnaO3l6c/YqOfz2/RG8uLna3OZQHm4uJAnEFuH3GWp97OZTcmCYBXWVKTvjetoTvbU/43lMOfDI5ympALqAodbmtYHsCpv0HOvvtEp29RRdvTn85fshouwy8eeWfT9o/99g10SEaSoajMnuQt1NV4PzTgfNKPMwSkC0O1uIDpti7zqSThVmaYXIHvpUJiFU6CN1o1FR5xo88YVzGWw4qX/mKArnMK9iD6bt2PhUA0zxWFe6fNIQ54Y@2JfzR9oQ/KhCeAnBMTmEQr@3HvRYaH8H/zx90hSXerGxJptGdTKl7IuPRDmQUn8hHT8Yn2dHCLPq4h14DGoqTzPmTRfKY6@jLJbaNxrgnRzN0BrFvfKQ8dTDWCoGXqL6Ku9XSQbovkXlbNidSc837R9bDD@S61n1zUcGwgmERDGWz1qb4o692qjYbRG9NkN8YlL613cUdQ/j6rMp2eduFL07eZ@uJXn5bWTC24GTuPoT9BDsbKsZzXMO0pbUrX7npQDkPYbrEgdYa8Bla6P48NqHK4YGe@DUZlXmpKjugnoewsfCeVSm6OpUBCw0ICtprA/rk9r1amhZYEDS01xbU3Unlg4UW1Pc9ioIJq0C6zoj7HknBiFUwXWvFfY@my7mpievQGt8dHHQ73x32mt8eqTCS8aF6WJoqdftFHFQqqqewbnegfXUDJddjrKM9vg22nFllwT9dyprCD0z7aPGwtcVqKMWA@wx52C@VIAhs@aGQFfqfLvoBBw8BfMv08rBE/7e97nvlu1fbLSKPpxSdpV@BvwL/vcD/l30Hv2FOpxiaTKr74Qr6W4V@e3@gL3zxk4uhhSd5b3j49jY1BGzh1WlqD/sAFXmllBvYjaXrzFx90UKr1Et1eRZ3TaWR7XRQa8eTG3W60XojGngKAhibvKtPJITg5X07fbWcRBH5d83VchKUf9dw9oWo7ECe8DG3Y/qLqFf3UGp8XC/Has8PgwkMfB3MxgvHSAS9nOOwM9KLq5seNuCa17@yyX8rnGFBkGqYHhn@mLAw7ZnXZ@0omYv9wE2rqJbyj2atlpGCvd9cu7Khl9oz9OMt8kGgG/22BT1dO8YtMj1kOc5H6AfpPr3qOYE7wWgCDFrINWdz/4da8vMMnSDL/IhRD36@fPkS9tCFDpzA/9K@@dK2/x8)

2. Only Python2.7

```
print('0')
out#
```

The # stops the parsing of the keyword so it doesn't work.

3. Only SunSip

```
print('0',)
out #
```

Try it online in [Python 2.7](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728oLIkIz_PaMGCpaUlaboWGwuKMvNKNNQN1HU0ufJLSxSUIeJQaZgyAA) and [SunSip](https://tio.run/##7V1td9s2sv6uX4Eq9y4lW1IlJ@1NtKv0pK3T9Tmp7eO46e7Kujq0CElsKFLLlzheXf/23AHAN5AABVqSLTd0T2NZHAwGM88MwMEQXN76c8d@/nLpfvnyDL1/9/vp@9Mfz1vIcVH9fWCj9@ayXoML5mJpYfROt2eBPsPo97njYXSqLzB6P3cCy0Cnjo9@xOjcdWwnsCfYqNWgjeP6yNVtw1lEfy10fx599m696KMTf3JxrWbgKbrGU8fFYzewG81@rYbgx5wiG7rR2raGTJs07@ju7FMfLV3T9hvala0d9LrdbjOi1trtObaWYmpNo2Tvb21f/wzfMk2AgKbdWd4ClTNz9UXHs25sz75eoqGz9E3H9ka02Rn7o0//ID@sK/jQByVAB8ifmx6i3y2w5xGtgSIQ/mz6naSREX7oo5/xdTBDC8fAqcs3yWXT06/BBDe6a5v2zEsR2TkiG99Ypo09pBsGNsjop2CXdL84bvPGshB2Xcf10FQ3LeSZFrZ96zZF3PaojoCYKQvNzdncgv/JIDHynMCdYDQB0UVDdOOufgPMuOZkziwAo2ghD2PKg34Ngw@scPhgnuZfqdEIu0azltj0E2/PuKfYrlfd58@Hr3qLD9i9Jjj9lUgGxiDg8YIlgRloxTMBpuio0@10aYPuAvADvbKeDGKOMTEHGkCfBtcno2DKHkcWoXQ3ebpPTIqI11vd8jC9YDug96QLzDelJM8QNkwiLNER@CO4I6du30G@/hGThuFV@rVhungCNiRmX9C2U9P1fASMgwVYF@g9H@sGcqZw1XWC2RzpyMeffSC0mHQh/kG0SKRhb9TxlpbpU2xxJgkRIjVMxIq4aOcPx7Qb4XchEzbWMMqEIPt7BDLsIggF4QATet@97aMoaAB84gv48wQvfXRCLx0TaCeiCHFyCQpi2EN1wqkODoQNj2j3GlNd6ZaFjQ4Pk4gd1TFp1lno7sdgGcmEvYm@BI/wqGLN/@BEdBLfmMbGsSs1CFWTl5RaZBC1ZxQcgRP4y4CQhMEs@mHez1oym9HoyDcmSiWExGi0Ad85@bmZAxzoxQ4owfW9G9OfNzSkNfO0KXkOQaChY0MsN0ZoCKPVAwtivI3CjyNN2JoKM6C/hr3@KEcDUGMkZLzrBRD0CzoQNps4JB4FuJa/sFhATGuhg3EoWaROlNFmaoIai2WDqyE7OgLyGXxRMpDsYJ49pz@jqJVSoxIawFZKPADEUDNtrYU0YEd@kZFrIxVRpyDrixfTabc7WoX87h5AWu@juSSCXuuTj@T3zPEd8pvMHuQ3BMTA9TD5CMxhNIb6cF69evlyx8PxsKowRLNbE6amLskG6J0m8F0RIN3tG3pJYMF2Y9wkQ@vJ6dYjHa3Gw@6oYIAbDHI9UpTli@2BVnVUZzPymMTc5m5EV/dXBee8v7Wyjrxv1pLI9/jWYlE0DqL3jpzCkTR3HA9IuPJwUaiK1sV0DY@0SK4iBMZNYGHkmssGBaMGGC5jb8WguDEKRfJyCzpY6cqWdLK40u1OpymkauiqsHlq2UknMR1uTUerlFR0VVUHQeot1GsS2BOhSnFdLXVAZ0POtAceMyrDc1XE68Ethm0jWoAD0B7SXs@fv3w5maTt5Yb6AElig90PBL5TxHbnaia6RPTGdaqhRBIYzKPqN9ED2li/W3IjtE0/Qg/kSOUm4GhxvbuAnJuZJro10XazNM1AMoHZvq1RiwUtDXvGbutLJa69i/3AtcNmfGZnhv3xJ90KcIP@O9a9MYng9izKY0c/9DIsOTJkPJFp@3iG3fFS930MPQ6Qq/1v@4dht/1qdPhf/KAALC7uLHR/Mm9k2rVYL4JJIxwJyYkxEr7/Z2hqObrfz3xJ5iFQECY7BTZEmDaazHVXn0BfLeQ5i@hC/K3HEmX1bu/o@Yvvvv@fl6/qrQzPVOJrjmEZlmZJ3EWRbYYrzTqHWiFRZzLHk49EVTR3TTWO6EXs0a9ChXV4NVAlCI1wcNVhvwuMwbWWmwKahJgAGHa0fowQrdvRiqnbHHlbRB8amsoiMfX7iQlB2pyaE7Kho5MtDpIjDrHklQGB1LbU21ibhePiYoRQi1iY6A3VcQFiCD5Uue4EIN7EtJ0xaErsqXitw@YYyHFCs/lk82TikFmE0UWJSSxITKZ8nLZtogPU66KDA/oV46MKBoqf7UFBNVakmXdUmJeIGDzMjgtg9lRHuEPIF0bGA/bhOPfNWkdQDJmFrnAsztGzzTC2ixD9ASFWK6ZtlyHulOKsQB0NkAkdD3c9dbsceack97X03KyTCT7sS0n4YTCUxhmtLllxZMJ/sfvoENLoTr5ucRyljS4dCJmGOdF9jHSuCdLZdji26b4qE1/eOyGjg/FvHGQ4Adm3/3fg@Di1tb9VZ6WEvJ/WOwf1H4o8kWsjd0JuISvbumOemeQw6rIMBs@t3@6NZKCiFFncxAaRQ0fLQSez0uRgkaLuSM1Z1wALN6ZlwS2ADVZkS9hUU7KPbBqYQKNe342J4754K19pnSutyMy5dptYOm0auHur1aRL1uEIYkdIbpkeKfKQ0q7uEloPF5L@7XWOrZz4NqG9dDP7vxyhnRCyCg7R3eApoIu/F/Rvl3jcEGkTuJserS2wJ@GdYgtdO47VjDvSyJ/a@lawhks1MrO7w8I2NPSmWtG/FdoBGFOtGDQVmhFDpNrprqvfqvSG061IEl@kds0GvWu84lkOS6R4DsJRblVueEv3/MT2Wrd7dPTypaaEKCD@/vtuV1NClUZIs8QAH1LFQUGUSSs0eZlhSqLxyr2FBqucV1JU9JE2mZBsi9bKEzAAFJKE1gaaFy/owAQ0zLJAcnREFSVig/1iAmpOoGDZuAzFnQgByeiHoKwRDwVS0ddoCmuArmyNLkaimsGUkVRqB6OfbA0hq@1RqCKMfnLVhJmqwjI1hfLquXTllGAhbeExqYMBbdFJX1T/xbWK6qxsA38WlFml1RwWWl3Zp05cDeYt8QRuLkldlTSZqJGJkUx4oR6Y8mjlkrRJQPVCyFMFW82/5shLaYetHZbYbkj0REpMtCap9pqKVzWJPqcdF@tGJuaEynwL3OFm@60T2EahTqexUt87rnvbQidoAqsWUn40hQVqWPRn4b5UUVNtJRnLXUfe5sr@ia5NwlXIvIVsfYHZqomwg4H4GFY6jl3I5C1YMDFUCz4L7Jy2n7L5aCUe01GuxC4qOkw1YcGhlioeTFiCUGNamEpudFxBeWYYfWIIJEWjrVx5aCtmV6uVbAD9p6uhazUIT9E1hg9aCxkXIkYViFQLtXUlkfcvhyR1kLnUPHz3xiKLSN03P2ELkOksTHZnRJU4tfRZppKyFk/YEQJjS/UztahDM95vJ0HAJDYJr46ypIQ2rtWDpWgr2dvnrpDdgZECuz@4rv8gtKasHY@MWsJGPExi0QQL/cTH7XNG0b@yV5F3UndI6Sy9KOhHdcNhyrZfW5ueK5863fR@RWVLo9RWhmQLg9u62OaWxXa3KjZVp/rWRIktCbWtCNUtCOnWg@KWg0J@ebtbDBttLWxq0FJbCSW3EJS3DkpsGShtFdzDhFtJnG91S0B1K2CfRrJFSG6U6i@d4ldO7auk9JVS@UopfLXUvVrKXjFVr5iiV03Nl0zJ86n4e6fgS6XeN065l0m1b@wca1LrZVLq8gSrSgq9IHWeT5nnUuVbTJFvmhrf1CQqqfCSKXC5ZYQpb5VUt0KKWym1vTalrZDKJredcMfx4c27347RilLfodOzS3Rx/NPZL@jNJXp3cgpXJoHrwlw/JiVyh727MAyH/Lq1TNK7hSa6i6eBNegSjbomucX1Bqu7ULGkGI4R8AnsRGKS0TDtpC0tL4u7CL8cUtpRrLISmfUyGfWymfSSGfSSmfMyGfPQupFdL/95fpwYl@QKubHS5xOpYFwGndWpEdXHSelwLZ/GWEgwiHLOEaR9t5g6SkCr0sfZ6LBBXasfMsiENZOs9WDQY5CBaMmuH8InCU8Ki/xNUKLQ29wsqtkyZlEqPCIcaodaK0xAhNo1U2kMJu6hNpLxY3nziNtKjdud0P7vLy@UfDvBRZehgjyha2KDCkUyh59geoc5IEKf79Ar4PUpTq2o1YDEoxBLZJlaBCXyXSNkR2tfSYq/H3VAGrFPw5jRKGqaYh2T9fn5L3IfJlc/Us/Jr@fvmG/8dHb6YV3My3bFAheZG2Mp87DmboGFXFiDHB/OmeJMx7ff9iRsQvfI8YlnOq2fm7iEjBiMc3w4NJL5qmhMhDjHIeMfHn0sv0HntfQOl7JAPnmUTGxoBWnC5rWkXgL@ps/8etzYqOvTIy063jyYTi3coKS5O2f6bQmgsNjDif/NoFsKIwIWryUcKKkiyJplWAjxnrAqidYMRrLGUOZTDq0yJjzCBMLw1Pz8xE2opZAtcFmYTEpgW8RgpZWCVopFPvv3GnUTxoeC9ODf0gTt/Bza1Uo4yuOIIkZ7kSyKqwYlCAiDw3BUAgNCDtx9RtYJCNg3E0Sss4xPl2ucc@RSwSnjwVIFSgKAcPCaVo4JF2OTdWo5JsIomzArs0DJmuMAZrcZbvRabLHca45KMMuZJ8usjGRZa6lKJglh0oEmS6nSPKXj5XiWW@lJh60ipyR@lAMd9jfkIJHifqgViqPEKlzW/3Z6/I9zdHxxUbSip7c3Fva8ht5C1/wdTJKsYLcqejOvEh1mFtndEbCjxBmuQqaZga1jy8hVGGfXI@s4h/QqrPm4uI4xpVZhGzpsPHdew3K8iDGjF3GOjjuit8bMnRZw30zwojdbFM7XzWa@QpPhYWiOABL0Xx4VRaWjtClrpBc0TY4DS60OmFygRiaY2JzciQbrVEOoZYoJ0yXA9/Ug7FEiXqxCPV/LGiXqrouHRlVFn5J0sQ7rJqG3JXogOgQFZkUnDPC/A926t7MOBrvx1jV8N3HXNaw38Nc1nB/JYSPxBoPrHXtAdMMraa5LRE0SWxTqVKrck8plx59lyiYmF5PKrUaG0AabB7TytUVqgfQFptttSbI88YVUdVEtV0lo/8T4onfAt8/PjnepjdakwUnSNdCnBBGTn8fCAXUiqZj4QyR9n@xDhJ/zpCwK0Ck@LIZNRktiUbaerp86aTCgm0sGmjiWw04XjKgE8kR1cb@/uTg9Of0FpAr7u0vXJzIzBfHJhikrADLJkwGJeKkr7FKfI16xGue0FeDbbi1XncqO52v3YKbgiNnEwdfQJc@Tx7Yi5WiMZphuPopSgbEqYoNJW2RKg@8L19yTGtQH@kDtebXcMQrcUNguuxphfHiZIr1pa8KHtdOKkZ9JSIrJ6VME3D6W/ISEZFeLNRuRyGYvA78hz75nWking@Y9zp@LV9E/H79FH95cINIHOjkVLKXvtGapYXX3RAlyBQDXMalwZqWbobWFT41w6Z@w0e4NHnW1Y5Ovon7uNjF8LOzOTF9WHUJ3J6cGPqC/s5nmK/Lt3Q34cf1YdVx/Qp/d1dCF/kmP83yCDtoilWgDTfvqHFU@8D@Lw27VtE/TccUqEDqw@DRO7jZDQ9ph8sWhhoQnUSSH9yW0xXCidxvjqJYvjazwgSB6FGYJFtG3ETRTV5XRGt68pCDPPKqoYVLPV3x6nCjScQMo6CrGLteAPuWuJFn47HRGXXzQkJ@SlzT7JnWXnLZd6uGn8PvmesG@yd1yc64SE5aIVdw@Q1HJULFXkCORH3Ba41IGhwNUJs7L8qNPYFLb9bAfd0orP7p0ZN@RWR9yQtutAoSOe81Xjj2s47Y3RvBh70m67k4GvkfO294Cdrdj2kdz3x2oQOjA9OUDj@XAG8O4/TT9dxfj3iP33QJ020/be7evAaHz0ndT9NG1i/WPCls/4uO2p4EdbkwdpF8GIbg/FGgr3WKYtBeegifb0IoFjiRhG@qGYZI/5HFHt6zGMNwWDztukQK5aEdtMGC1dWSPM/X6t0TmUcF7BLxgUWhuKdPi479TLzfIPd7VX3vSdx7gETMJwPO3X8VQj9gVQz3Sj9ISM2ZZYo0tC6/Q6T3CQmjKTmXMrRpTXs@ziTnzgcALrn1SaP54sSD9RpJhd1TS1nI7e/SI/3vaOm8Uwq7Y1swT1M1MOZb0W6mGyXPDX5E/tZ9GcPzqsV0ujFXovie6H2q2WASWb4JgE/3RF4@9ar1RoJ@Dp7R47FWLx@0a86HCgWF@Mr3iQGDfNoZSSyDHLTlTjQaDbvE0URQ5Qrv@fPIB/fhP9K/ji7P7mFM9NcVet1ctnqvF817Fk2@rxXO1eK7Q/eCLZ3L0saM6V@5ynqzmyGqOrKJIYRT572qOrObICt0PPUcunRvuyJtH24ho9/bYmUC4bXsTYbm1qaLd63fJGbFfiUeR45GDxWCw8YQBizblgdOV2fnZ7/deoqWwMuitpSIvczHtABcS0reFlMWeRBfkzGjZnBjHD/b2kX9h1/k5TEVJ3m2zm1WuajnDjub7rzRGbWvKryLUfSb9R4lRIgfq7SYUCQf9NQaj/OKMnJojWZv5Ln10JndeUdoLU2ck0WOBIkdstnuqqzJzmwHP3G7AM9fEO34gh1uN3YTddgdzuC58hxanv8gZavRIJYleWvI@VMK4CLG@K3yQKgvZ8DCoCrUVaoWojQ4L2zvg0kPIKthWsBXClh1RVx606jC9VIPp0llKQJrUrh8OUMz4AH1X224ecwe3NGXzl3StKTxcpmQ6c@3abt2P@OA74evUU0vWohftZtR8fnaO3l6c/YqOfz2/RG8uLna3OZQHm4uJAnEFuH3GWp97OZTcmCYBXWVKTvjetoTvbU/43lMOfDI5ympALqAodbmtYHsCpv0HOvvtEp29RRdvTn85fshouwy8eeWfT9o/99g10SEaSoajMnuQt1NV4PzTgfNKPMwSkC0O1uIDpti7zqSThVmaYXIHvpUJiFU6CN1o1FR5xo88YVzGWw4qX/mKArnMK9iD6bt2PhUA0zxWFe6fNIQ54Y@2JfzR9oQ/KhCeAnBMTmEQr@3HvRYaH8H/zx90hSXerGxJptGdTKl7IuPRDmQUn8hHT8Yn2dHCLPq4h14DGoqTzPmTRfKY6@jLJbaNxrgnRzN0BrFvfKQ8dTDWCoGXqL6Ku9XSQbovkXlbNidSc837R9bDD@S61n1zUcGwgmERDGWz1qb4o692qjYbRG9NkN8YlL613cUdQ/j6rMp2eduFL07eZ@uJXn5bWTC24GTuPoT9BDsbKsZzXMO0pbUrX7npQDkPYbrEgdYa8Bla6P48NqHK4YGe@DUZlXmpKjugnoewsfCeVSm6OpUBCw0ICtprA/rk9r1amhZYEDS01xbU3Unlg4UW1Pc9ioIJq0C6zoj7HknBiFUwXWvFfY@my7mpievQGt8dHHQ73x32mt8eqTCS8aF6WJoqdftFHFQqqqewbnegfXUDJddjrKM9vg22nFllwT9dyprCD0z7aPGwtcVqKMWA@wx52C@VIAhs@aGQFfqfLvoBBw8BfMv08rBE/7e97nvlu1fbLSKPpxSdpV@BvwL/vcD/l30Hv2FOpxiaTKr74Qr6W4V@e3@gL3zxk4uhhSd5b3j49jY1BGzh1WlqD/sAFXmllBvYjaXrzFx90UKr1Et1eRZ3TaWR7XRQa8eTG3W60XojGngKAhibvKtPJITg5X07fbWcRBH5d83VchKUf9dw9oWo7ECe8DG3Y/qLqFf3UGp8XC/Has8PgwkMfB3MxgvHSAS9nOOwM9KLq5seNuCa17@yyX8rnGFBkGqYHhn@mLAw7ZnXZ@0omYv9wE2rqJbyj2atlpGCvd9cu7Khl9oz9OMt8kGgG/22BT1dO8YtMj1kOc5H6AfpPr3qOYE7wWgCDFrINWdz/4da8vMMnSDL/IhRD36@fPkS9tDVWs2aE/jo2Zf2zZe2/f8)

Outputs `('0',)` in python

4. Neither SunSip not Python 2.7

Obviously does nothing in either program.

Comment: Dang I had pretty much the same thing, except I couldn't get the Sunsip interpreter to work for some reason (was trying to get TIO links for Sunsip).

Comment: Yea I couldn't get the online interpreter to work either, had to download it

Comment: It looks like it only takes programs from text files, that's why it doesn't work on TIO. I edited the source code to take in the program directly as an argument, not sure if that's allowed though.

Comment: @AidenChow Probably fine if you are just changing the input method, but you need to be careful not to accidentally create a version of the language from after the challenge was posted

Comment: Also the code for the first block should be `out` in the second line, not `end`.

Comment: Can I edit the links directly into your post?

Comment: Ok I've edited the links into your post, if there's any problems you can always rollback the edit.

Comment: Yes that's fine

Answer (score 2):

## A = [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), B = [Adapt](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/adapt), [mousetail](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251486/31957)

Although this outputs a trailing newline for **B**, [mousetail has clarified this is acceptable](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/251450/polyglot-quiz-cops-thread/251486?noredirect=1#comment560278_251486).

1. [`2` in ><>](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X1mhoCgzr0RDyQgBlDQV9PW5FGOwySgrGHHFxCiAgIaSIQIoadrY5HFZ4wL//wMA), [`2` in Adapt](https://tio.run/##S0xJLCj5/19ZoaAoM69EQ8kIAZQ0FfT1uRRjsMkoKxhxxcQogICGkiECKGna2ORxWeMC//8DAA)
2. [`2` in ><>](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X1mhoCgzr0RDyRAODJQ0FfT1uRRjsMkoKxhxxcQogACajI1NHpc1LvD/PwA), [`[]` in Adapt](https://tio.run/##S0xJLCj5/19ZoaAoM69EQ8kQDgyUNBX09bkUY7DJKCsYccXEKIAAmoyNTR6XNS7w/z8A)
3. [no output & errors in ><>](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/v6AoM69EQ8kIAZQ0FfT1uRRjsMkoKxhxxcQogICGkiECKGna2ORxWeMC//8DAA), [`2` in Adapt](https://tio.run/##S0xJLCj5/7@gKDOvREPJCAGUNBX09bkUY7DJKCsYccXEKICAhpIhAihp2tjkcVnjAv//AwA)
4. [`1` in ><>](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X1mhoCgzr0RDyRABlDQV9PW5FGOwySgrGHLFxMQoAAGajJ1dHpc1LvD/PwA), [`1` in Adapt](https://tio.run/##S0xJLCj5/19ZoaAoM69EQ8kQAZQ0FfT1uRRjsMkoKxhyxcTEKAABmoydXR6XNS7w/z8A)

Comment: Not what I intended but still good find

Comment: Seems like it prints `2` with a newline in Adapt, which does not match the original string (which is `2` by itself, no newline).

Comment: @AidenChow I'll get back to it then. Deleting until I figure it out truly.

Answer (score 1):

## Vyxal and Jelly, cracks Number Basher's answer

1. empty program, [Vyxal](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCIiLCIiLCIiXQ==), [Jelly](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8DwQA)
2. `!`, [Vyxal](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCIhIiwiIiwiIl0=), [Jelly](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/x/38A)
3. `r`, [Vyxal](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJyIiwiIiwiIl0=), [Jelly](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/o/38A)
4. `"`, [Vyxal](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJcIiIsIiIsIiJd), [Jelly](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/p/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## A = [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), B = [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), [Mukundan314](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251476/92689)

1. Try it online in [Pyth](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P0cpMdH4/38A) and [V](https://tio.run/##K/v/P0cpMdH4/38A).
2. Try it online in [Pyth](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/3/j/fwA) and [V](https://tio.run/##K/v/3/j/fwA).
3. Try it online in [Pyth](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PyXHOMDw8Erj//8B) and [V](https://tio.run/##K/v/PyXHOMDw8Erj//8B).
4. Try it online in [Pyth](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfgPBAA) and [V](https://tio.run/##K/sPBAA).

Answer (score 1):

## 0SAB1LE and yup, [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251484/31625)

1. [0SAB1LE](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fQNn@/38A), [yup](https://tio.run/##qywt@P/fQNn@/38A)
2. [0SAB1LE](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fwP7/fwA), [yup](https://tio.run/##qywt@P/fwP7/fwA)
3. [0SAB1LE](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fQPn/fwA), [yup](https://tio.run/##qywt@P/fQPn/fwA)
4. [0SAB1LE](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f4P9/AA), [yup](https://tio.run/##qywt@P/f4P9/AA)

I just went through everything on TIO that looked like a stack based language until I found one that worked.